# Why does the order matter in closures?

Tags: rust

In rust, order of the functions do not matter unlike C or C++ where main function should be at the end. But it is not the same for closures and I wonder why

For example, this code compiles:

```
fn main(){
    println!("{}", add_up(1));
}
fn add_up(x: i32) -> i32{
    x + y
}
const y:i32 = 1;
```

and this code does not compile:

```
fn main(){
    let add_up = |x:i32| x + y;
    let y = 1;
    println!("{}", add_up(1));
}
```

I know in the first one y is a global variable and that is not a fair comparison but this is the example I can think of at the moment. The main point is, generally order does not matter in rust (where is main located or where is add_up located) but not the same for closures. Why?

Comment: It's hard to answer a "why" question when something is not a bug, but a design decision. In this case I believe the underlying reasoning is that a globally defined constant and statics don't have "scope", they are available before the program starts and last for as long as the program. Because of that it doesn't hurt to make them visible "before" their definition. On the other hand, local variables have clear scope (place where they're introduced and where they're destructed), so it doesn't make sense to "see" them before or after that.

Comment: Since the definition is "Closures are anonymous functions that capture their environment" I would assume that they would also capture this. It's not clear to me @user4815162342

Comment: (Off-topic) I think it's easier to answer design decisions since there is an underlying logic. It should be harder for the bugs since they can be very random :d

Comment: @merovingian a closure is quite literally a struct with whatever it captures stored as attributes. So it is a completely sequential construct. Unlike a static item which is always there.

Comment: "It should be harder for the bugs since they can be very random :d" that doesn't make any sense, what are you talking about? Rust is a sequential, procedural language. `let y = x+1; let x = 0;` doesn't work either. It's not Prolog.

Comment: But capture - what? Let's say you have code like `let c = || x; let x = 1; let x = x + 1; { let x = 100; }`, which of the `x`es should `c` capture? How would it even do that when none of them exist at the time `c` is created? My point is that a global isn't created at any "time", it always exists.

Comment: Bugs are not intentional things, that is what I'm talking about @Masklinn

Comment: I still have no idea what you're talking about. You wrote nonsense, the compiler stops you, there is no bug, your code is just broken.

Comment: *I think it's easier to answer design decisions since there is an underlying logic.* - in some cases there's a clear logic, but sometimes that logic is unknow or not obvious. And some design decisions are just arbitrary, or matters of taste or history or whatever. C could support orderless access to globals as well, but it doesn't because its creators wanted to support single-pass parsers, or for whatever other reason that is now lost in the mists of time. Some "why" questions can only be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Well, it is hard for me not to laugh at the moment xd. Look at the above comment: "It's hard to answer a "why" question when something is not a bug, but a design decision. ". I was replying to this one :d I did not say "that is a bug" I made a general off-topic comment @Masklinn

Comment: Understood your point. Makes sense to me. Thanks @user4815162342

Comment: No reason to get personal about Masklinn. Many of us are not native English speakers, so please accept some problems in understanding.

Comment: I am also not a native speaker. It's not that he doesn't understand, it is because he doesn't read and gets unnecessarily angry @thebusybee

Comment: Thanks, I've now posted an answer that summarizes my point.

Comment: I don't see any anger in Masklinn's comments. And even if you understood some word as such, there is no point in hitting back. You seem to want empathy, so please apply some.

Comment: @merovingian I think his comment indeed came across a little harsh, but I agree with his general content, the discussion did indeed become a little confusing :)

Comment: @Masklinn I think he tried to say that this question should be easier to answer, because it does *not* contain a bug. Because it is a question to explain a design decision, which has logic and thought behind it. He never tried to say that the behavior of his code contains a bug.

Comment: Wasn't it clear what I was talking about? I think the confusing part is the transition from design decisions to having some empathy part :) @Finomnis

Comment: @merovingian no, the comments were pretty out of order, so I think Masklinn actually lost track of what you are talking about. That's what he was trying to say with "you are taking nonsense", I don't think that he meant to attack you. Granted, it could have been worded more graceful.

Comment: I agree, I also don't want to get personal on StackOverflow, I want to talk about computer science objectively. But sometimes...yeah. Thanks for making my point more clear by the way @Finomnis

Comment: @merovingian I think the most important concept to understand regarding your actual question is what Masklinn said in his first comment: "a closure is quite lit..."

Comment: @merovingian With other words: a closure is just an object, and creating it follows the same rules as creating a struct object or a primitive would. Code in a function is executed sequentially, and creating a closure is just another sequential action. Opposed to function definitions or global consts/statics, which are definitions, not actions. Evaluating them is done by the compiler, not at runtime.

Comment: Coming from a mathematical background I'm very careful with definitions. As I pointed out above, I think the definition was misleading me. Because when I hear the word "environment" I don't think of a top-the-bottom sequential approach, I think of whatever the environment contains (inside the function in this case). It does not necessarily have to be in this way I understand now. @Finomnis

Comment: @merovingian That's the case for purely functional languages. Rust is a multi-paradigm language with functional elements, but in its base it's an imperative language.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between a local variable (which can be captured by a closure) and a constant or static is that the latter don't have "scope", they are available before the program starts and last for as long as the program. A variable, on the other hand, has a clear scope - a place where it's introduced and a place where it's destructed, and attempt to use it outside that region cannot work.

For example, if it were allowed to capture variables that are not yet created might result in non-sensical code like this:

```
let c = || x;
println!("{}", c());  // what does this print?
let x = some_function_that_takes_user_input();
let x = x + 1;
{
    let x = 100;
}
```

A static or a const, on the other hand, doesn't have this issue because it's not created at any time, it always exists for as long as the program.

Comment: This explanation doesn't really work for me because Statics and constants clearly have scope. You can't use a static that's defined in a function outside the function, or a const that's defined in a module in a different module; that is its scope. The decision to make the scope of a constant declared in a function the entire function, rather than from the declaration to the end of the function, is more or less arbitrary.

Comment: @trent They have scope for visibility, but not to decide when they start and end existing in time. But I see your point.

Comment: The usual (borrowed from C) name for that concept is "storage duration" (or "lifetime", but obviously that term would be a bit overloaded here)